# Without reopening a file, the integer contents are changing from the last time I serialized them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, save

I'm trying to save over older data, but it seems either the save isn't working or the data is getting changed after I serialize it.

I've looked through every script and put console messages on each one that opens the file (of which there are only 2) and nothing is opening the file between when I serialize it and when I open it up and get different data.

This is the code that serializes the new information

```
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + "Checkpoint.dat", FileMode.Open);
            CheckpointData data = (CheckpointData)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(file);
            data.Checkpoint = CheckpointNumber;
            Player.CheckpointNumber = CheckpointNumber;
            if (data.CheckpointUnlocked == CheckpointNumber - 1)
            {
                Player.CheckpointUnlocked = CheckpointNumber;
                data.CheckpointUnlocked = CheckpointNumber;
            }
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(file, data);
            file.Close();
```

This is what opens the file upon reloading the scene after serializing the data:

```
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + "Checkpoint.dat", FileMode.Open);
            CheckpointData data = (CheckpointData)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(file);
            CheckpointNumber = data.Checkpoint;
            print(data.Checkpoint);
            CheckpointUnlocked = data.CheckpointUnlocked;
            print(data.CheckpointUnlocked);
            file.Close();
```

It should change the checkpoint and checkpointunlocked integers from 1 to 2, but they are loaded again as 1 in the second section of code.

Comment: *"It should change the checkpoint and checkpointunlocked integers from 1 to 2"* What is "it" in this context? Where do those two values get changed?

Comment: The values are changed due to the code preceding the first snippet of code, and I tested it by writing the values that were changed to the console and also, that the data.checkpoint and data.checkpointunlocked integers got the correct values as well, before it serialized it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. I used to use File.Create to change the file, but when I wanted to get data from the file, edit it, and then save that data, I still used the binaryFormatter.Serialize(file, data); Which didn't seem to work when Opening a file. Either that or you can't deserialize something and then serialize it afterwards. Once I changed the code around so I never used deserialize in the first example and I used file.Create instead of file.Open . I imagine there is probably a way to do this with writing to the file instead of overwriting it, but this works, and I'll go research how to do that instead later.